# How to use two y-axes on a matplotlib plocontourf plot e.g. log pressure and altitude

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-3.7

I'm using contourf and contour in python 3.7 to plot temperature in an atmosphere. I want to plot latitude against both log base 10 of pressure AND pseudo-altitude calculated from that pressure.

[example of the plot against just pseudo-altitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vblgJ.png)

I've tried using twinx() but that doesn't seem to work with contourf.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

''' below is the altitude (z) plot '''
#cs = T(ds, z, lat).plot.contourf(cmap = 'RdBu_r', levels=np.arange(150, 290, 10), yincrease=True)
#plt.ylabel('Approx. Altitude (km)', fontsize='large')
#plt.ylim(min(z), 80)

''' below is the log pressure (p) plot ''
cs = T(ds, p, lat).plot.contourf(levels=np.arange(150, 290, 10), yincrease=False) 
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure (hPa)')
ax.set_yscale('log', basey=10)
```

How do I plot 2 y-axes on a contour plot?

(p.s. this is my first ever post, please let me know if you need more info!)

Comment: `ax2 = ax.twinx()` will get you a second y axis. It's not clear from the code why that wouldn't work. Of course you will need to plot to those axes and the construct `T(ds, p, lat).plot.contourf` may be a bit too condensed to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Hi, my apologies, I should have said that T(...) is just calling an xarray dataset. That dataset is defined by pressure (p) and latitude (lat) coordinates. When I use twinx() I am plotting the same but with altitude (z) instead of pressure. Do you think it is because I’m using xarrays or could it be an issue with using contourf?

Comment: I don't know how much about xarray's plotting functions, so I think I would need a [mcve] (runnable code) to work out a solution here. Just a conceptional question though: Do you really want to plot two filled contours on top of each other? I would imagine the one overlaying the other such that you only see one of them anyways.